# Asynchronous webservice in cxf

Tags: cxf, jax-ws-customization, contract-first

I need to send a response unsolicitedly from my server side to client side using cxf.I am very much comfortable in making synchronous JAX-WS calls from client to server(I used SOPAUI to invoke my server which is a webservice_..I am following JAX-WS wsdl first approach.I am using cxf 'wsdltojava' to convert wsdl to java classes.

To make it simple,my question is 'how to send a response(without a request from client) from server to client in CXF,JAX-WS wsdl first approach?

Comment: Well you just can't !. To achieve some "push" from server to clients, use atmosphere (comet) : http://atmosphere.java.net/

Comment: Can u please provide a java solution?